# I install joomla 1.6 wamp server and i create a site.Is it needed to install joomla1.6 again to create next site?

Tags: php

I am new to joomla1.6.I install joomla1.6 in my folder named joomla inside the www folder on wampserver.Then i create my first site.Is it needed to install joomla1.6 again for creating the second site?is it needed to install joomla1.6 again&again for each site?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you're searching for the multi-sites extensions: [Multiple Sites in the extension repository](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites).

Comment: I am new to joomla.please explain yhat is it possible to create my second site with out installing joomla again.